# Locally compiled c++ code is improperly looping

Tags: c++, g++

The following never terminates on my system.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int solutions[1000][4] = {};
    

    for(int a=0; 3*a<=1000; a++){
        for(int b=0; 5*b<=1000; b++){
            for(int c=0; 7*c<=1000; c++){
                cout << "enter" << "\t" << a << "\t" << b << "\t" << c << endl;
                if (3*a+5*b+7*c > 1000) {break;}
                solutions[3*a+5*b+7*c][0] = a;
                solutions[3*a+5*b+7*c][1] = b;
                solutions[3*a+5*b+7*c][2] = c;
                solutions[3*a+5*b+7*c][3] = 1;
                cout << "exit" << "\t" << a << "\t" << b << "\t" << c << endl << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm completely stumped, so I decided to print a log of variable changes. It makes it to 4 iterations of b, and then when c hits 140, it loops back to 0. Log looks like this

```
...
enter   0       4       137
exit    0       4       137

enter   0       4       138
exit    0       4       138

enter   0       4       139
exit    0       4       139

enter   0       4       140
exit    0       4       0

enter   0       4       1
exit    0       4       1

enter   0       4       2
exit    0       4       2

enter   0       4       3
exit    0       4       3
...
```

I compiled this using `g++ B.cpp -o B.exe`, and then just ran the executable. The exact code (with logging commented out) terminates properly online at http://cpp.sh/. My compiler version is `g++ (i686-posix-dwarf-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 5.3.0`. What could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `a = 0, b = 4, c = 140`, `3*a+5*b+7*c` becomes `1000` and write to out-of-bounds `solution[1000]` happens. It seems this out-of-bound write happened to break the loop counter.

Allocate one more element to avoid this out-of-bounds write.

```
    int solutions[1001][4] = {};
```

Comment: Yes this was exactly it. Does that mean the out of bounds area that was overwritten was exactly the variable c? Or could other things have happened in this undefined write to cause this?

Comment: @eeegnu Out-of-bound write invokes *undefined behavior*. Anything is allowed to happen for *undefined behavior*.